# Designing a custom small DDoS detection and defense sytem

Tags: networking, security, libraries, denial-of-service, algorithm

Am very new to the topic so I would like some guidance where to get started.
What I want is, some tools to programmatically observe network traffic and preform some actions on the traffic. I don't want ready-made​ solution that protects about DDoS, because I want to control the algorithm of detection, and the algorithm of blocking the traffic but I need tools to do so, some kind of hooks to act upon the network. Also do I determine if a particular traffic is a DDoS attack?

Preferably on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is the 'go-to' tool for network sniffing.

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/);

Beyond this, you're pretty much left teaching yourself about info sec. You'd likely do better by reading up at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, thanks,  but about Wireshark, I know it as and end user software, can it be used programmatically, or like a library?

Comment: It uses the pcap library I believe, which you can also use. If you're interested in programming then you should be asking on stackoverflow, not here...